# Delete Selected row of selected ID using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to delete a row of selected ID by passing a parameter into URL. let say, I have entryIDs 1 and 2, whenever I try to select and delete the content of entry 1, it successfully deletes the content of entryID 1 but the problem is when I choose to delete entryID 2 it still deletes entryID 1 instead of 2. I am thinking the content of a variable `var row = '".$rows['Blog_ID']."';` doesn't change and only retains the value of entryID 1 even though I choose otherwise.

Here is what I tried so far..

```
<?php
include("../Connection.php");
$post_query="Select * from indexview order by Blog_ID Desc";
$postsql=mysqli_query($connect_db,$post_query) or die('Connection unsuccessful');

    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($postsql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo "<div id='posts'>";
    echo" <select onchange = 'down(this.value)' id='downpng' name='downpng'>
                <option value='void'></option>
                <option value = 'edit'>Edit Blog</option>
                 <option value ='delete'>Delete</option>
        </select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​";


        echo 
        "<script>

             function down(temp) {

                var row = ".$rows['Blog_ID'].";
                var id = '".$_GET['id']."';



                if(temp=='delete'){

                    var con = confirm('Are you sure?');
                    if(con){
                        window.location = 'google.php?entryID=' + row + '&id=' + id;

                        }else{
                            window.location = '../Blog/Blog.php?id=".$_GET['id']."';
                        }

    }else{
        window.location = '../Blog/edit.php';
    }
}
</script>";
```

When I select `<option value ='delete'>Delete</option>` it is supposed to redirect me into deleteBlog.php page and delete the content of selected entryID.

deleteBlog.php code:

```
<?php
include("../Connection.php");

if(isset($_GET['entryID'])){


$user = $_GET['id'];
$entry = $_GET['entryID'];

mysqli_query($connect_db, "Delete from blog_tbl where Blog_ID=" .$entry);
header('Location: ../Blog/Blog.php?id='.$user);

}

?>
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should be using javascript to extract the id from the html element instead of using php to generate a bunch of js functions/script in a loop. You should have one js function (that is not created by php) and gets the id from the html element and submits it using only the one function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do minimal php for this, especially when it comes to the javascript part. Just store the blog id (I am going to store it in the name of the select attribute) and extract via javascript. I am going to use jQuery to do the JS stuff.

```
<?php
# Include database
include("../Connection.php");
# Create a simple function that does not use id="downpng" (id values are 
# supposed to be unique
function getOrderDropDown($con)
    {
        $query   = "Select * from indexview order by Blog_ID Desc";
        $postsql = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Connection unsuccessful');
        $str     = '';
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($postsql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $str .= "
        <select name='downpng[".$rows['Blog_ID']."]' class='blog_select'>
            <option value='void'></option>
            <option value = 'edit'>Edit Blog</option>
            <option value ='delete'>Delete</option>
        </select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​";
        }
        return $str;
    }

# Write the selects to page
echo getOrderDropDown($connect_db);
?>
```

Javascript to extract the selection:

```
<script>
// I would only do php here, use a special chars, otherwise you will be easily hacked by user input
var id = <?php echo (!empty($_GET['id']))? '"'.htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'],ENT_QUOTES).'"' : 'false' ?>;
// On change of this class type
$('.blog_select').on('change',function(e) {
    // Get the name (which contains the id)
    var row     =   $(this).attr('name').replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'');
    // This will be the action (delete, edit)
    var action  =   $(this).val();
    // On delete, assign the actions and send values
    if(action == 'delete'){
        var redirect;
        var con =   confirm('Are you sure?');
        if(con){
            redirect    =   'google.php?entryID='+row+'&id='+id;
        }else{
            redirect    =   '../Blog/Blog.php?id='+id;
        }
    }else{
        redirect    =   '../Blog/edit.php';
    }
    // Just do one redirect
    window.location =   redirect;
});
</script>
```